# HelloRestAPI showing 404 (created with IntelliJ Spring Initializr)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am totally frustrated about that beginnerproblem
Simply startet a fresh SpringBoot Project with JDK18 and UpToDate IntelliJ.

Inserted no more Code that this Controller:

```
package com.example.springboot;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

calling: **curl localhost:8080**
and get an unusual 404:

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Searching for that response pointing me to very old threads talking about views jsp and web.xml

But I dont want to have nasty renderings. I want pure REST-Controller.

Any suggestion to point me to the correct issue or even better to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The spring-boot-starter-web dependency is required in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When you create a new project with IntelliJ it asks for the dependencies you want to include. Here you need to select "Spring Web":

[image]